# How to return true or false to for_each in this case?

Tags: c++, standard-library

In my code below I want to inform for_each if I find the item?  How do that?

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

class widget {
 public:
  widget(int id) : m_id(id) {}

private:
   int m_id;
};

class findwidget {
public:
   findwidget(widget* p) : m_widget(p) {}

   bool operator()(widget* p) const { 
      return p == m_widget ? true : false;
   }

   widget* m_widget;
};

list<widget*> m_widgetList;

void push_back(widget* pi){
   if(m_widgetList.empty()) {
      m_widgetList.push_back(pi);
   } else {
      if(!std::for_each(m_widgetList.begin(), m_widgetList.end(), findwidget(pi)))
         m_widgetList.push_back(pi);
   }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   widget w1(1);
   push_back(&w1);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is : Dont use `std::for_each`. Use any from the following (whatever suits your situation):

- [`std::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/)
- [`std::find_if`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/)
- [`std::find_first_of`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_first_of/)

Example of `std::find`:

```
if(std::find(m_widgetList.begin(), m_widgetList.end(),pi) == m_widgetList.end())
     m_widgetList.push_back(pi);
```

Note if you use `std::find`, you don't need the `findWidget` functor. After all, you're comparing just the addresses (i.e the pointers).

By the way, it seems that you want the list to contain *unique* elements, and don't want to keep duplicates. If that is so, then you better consider:

- [`std::set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/insert/)

`std::set` automatically will handle the dupilcate elements. That is, you can do this:

```
m_widgetSet.insert(pi);
```

then it will insert `pi` into the set if its not in it. And if its already containing it, `insert` will not insert it into the set.

Comment: +1 for `std::set` (I would consider `std::unordered_set` in C++0x too, since order does not seem to import). A proper choice of data structure is fundamental, uses of `std::list` are usually suspicious (simply because people seem to only know lists...).